# Microsoft Outlook Breaking My Table

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm coding an email for my place of work and because we are business to business, there's a lot of pressure for me to get emails to look nice in Microsoft Outlook. I originally had this set up as a 6 column table (I broke my first row into 6 empty divisions and used colspan), but reduced it to a 3 column table. I was sure that I had all my measurements right, but it seems that Microsoft Outlook is still breaking my table.

In Outlook, the right side of the 3rd, 4th and 5th rows jut out about 100px from the 1st and 2nd rows, and the 5th row, my footer, has the white text squashed into what looks like a 100px wide division and the button floats in the center of rest of the space.

I've quadruple checked my colspans and pixel measurements, as well as replacing my hr tags with .jpg images (but changed them back to hr tags when I found that that didn't make a difference), but it's still  giving me Hell. I've been looking at this way to long, I must be missing the problem over and over again.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w31.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>2015 Outdoor Room Design Ideas Promo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
.ExternalClass * {
width: 100%;
line-height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
margin: 0 auto !important;
}

table.container {
width: 100% !important;
border-collapse: collapse !important; 
mso-table-lspace:0; 
mso-table-rspace:0; 
table-layout: fixed ;
vertical-align: top !important;
}

table.layout {
width: 600px !important;
}

table.copy {
width: 550px !important;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #d1d1d1; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">
<table class="container" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%"><tr><td align="center">
    <table class="layout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600px">
        <tr><td width="200px" height="10px"></td><td width="200px" height="10px"></td><td width="200px" height="10px"></td></tr>

        <tr><td colspan="3" width="600px" height="50px">
                <img src="http://media.hearthandhome.com/promos/2015_Outdoor_Room/Header.jpg" width="600px" height="50px" alt="Hearth and Home magazine, the voice of the hearth, barbecue, and patio industries" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" width="600px" height="5px"></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" width="600px" height="347px">
                <img src="http://media.hearthandhome.com/promos/2015_Outdoor_Room/Image.jpg" width="600px" height="347px" alt="David Thorne Landscape Architect" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" width="600px" height="5px"></td></tr>

        <tr><td colspan="3" width="550px" height="auto" style="background-color: #FFF; padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 25px;">
            <h1 align="center" style="font-size: 22px; color: #477696;">We&#39;re Looking for a Few Great<br /> Outdoor Rooms</h1>      
<hr width="550px" style="border: 1px #d1d1d1 solid;" />          
<p style="color: #000000; font-size: 16px;">The August issue of <i>Hearth &amp; Home</i> will feature Outdoor Room Designs. From spectacular, over&#45;the&#45;top showstoppers, to modest, small-scale spaces, we plan to showcase outdoor living areas that will delight and inspire you, and your customers, no matter their budget or vision.</p>

<p style="font-size: 16px; word-spacing: -1px; color: #000000">We hope this Special Section in <i>Hearth &amp; Home</i> will be something you&#39;ll want to save for reference and share with your customers as a design resource and idea source while helping them create outdoor kitchens and living spaces in their backyards.</p>
<p style="color: #000000; font-size: 16px;">We invite you to share photos of outdoor projects you have worked on for possible inclusion in this section. Ideally, we would love to see projects that include outdoor kitchens, outdoor fireplaces or fire pits, AND outdoor dining and seating, but we&#39;ll gladly consider those that have only some of those elements.</p>
<p style="word-spacing: -1px; color: #000000; font-size: 16px;">Whether you or your business handled the entire project from inception to completion, or worked on just one aspect of it, such as the design, landscaping or supplying the outdoor kitchen appliances, hearth products, patio furniture or other products, we would love to see your photos and hear a little bit about the details.</p>

<p style="color: #000000; font-size: 16px;">Deadline for submissions will be <b>May 22, 2015</b>. All work will be properly credited to you.</p>

<hr width="550px" style="border: 1px #d1d1d1 solid;" />
            <p style="font-size: 19px; color: #477696; font-weight: 600"  align="center">Thanks! We can&#39;t wait to see<br /> your great Outdoor Rooms!</p>
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td colspan="3" width="600px" height="5px"></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" width="350px" height="80px" style="background-color: #477696; padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 25px;"><p style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 200">To submit your project for consideration, click the button to the right and fill out the submission form. When uploading your images, we encourage you to send <i>.zip files</i>. Not sure how to zip files? <a style="color: #FFF" href="http://www.wikihow.com/Zip-Files-Together" alt="How to zip files" target="_blank">Click here</a>.</p></td>
                <td width="200px" height="80px" style="background-color: #477696;"><a href="http://www.theoutdoorroom.com/form/" alt="Click here to submit your project" target="_blank"><img style="vertical-align: center;" src="http://media.hearthandhome.com/promos/2015_Outdoor_Room/Button.jpg" width="167px" height="61px" alt="Click here to submit your outdoor room project" /></a></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" width="600px" height="50px" style="vertical-align: center;"><p align="center" style="font-size: 14px; color: #000000"><i>Any questions, please contact<br />
</i></p></td></tr>
    </table>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I resolved my own issue.

It was the three empty cells at the top of the page, so I dropped from 3 columns to 2 columns. I've lost the nice spacing I had above the header, but it is no longer breaking in Outlook.